# Can I start an activity from Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler class in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am writing a custom exception handler class extending the `Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler`. The implementation is as below:

```
public class ExceptionHandler implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {
private final Activity crashedActivity;

    public ExceptionHandler(Activity activity) {
        this.crashedActivity = activity;
    }    
    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable exception) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(crashedActivity, SplashActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(CONSTANTS.APP_CRASHED, true);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
                        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                crashedActivity.startActivity(intent);
                crashedActivity.finish();
        }
}
```

While this code is compiling, it is not starting the new activity. Why is that? How to accomplish this?

Comment: This depends on the cause of the crash. How are you producing the crash? Also, are you sure this method is being called?

Comment: I am prducing the crash using `throw new NullPointerException();`

Comment: Are you sure that the method is being called?

Comment: Please post the code that you use to set up the `UncaughtExceptionHandler`

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to clarify is that **you must not try to re-start your app from a custom exception handler**, as the app may be in an unstable state. Custom exception handlers should be used to generate some type of crash logs which you may send to your servers, and/or show a friendlier error message (activity) to the user.

Checking your code seems you want to pass the crashed activity which will not work, as the exception handler to be more effective **should be instantiated in the [Application](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application) class**, at which point no Activity has been created yet.

With this in mind, try the next code. As said, **it should instantiated only once in your [Application](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application) class**.

Replace **YourCrashNotificationActivity.class** by the Activity you will use to notify about the problem, and ensure that such Activity has minimal code and is 100% bug free, because if it fails then the crash handler **uncaughtException** will be triggered again, meaning you will fall into a loop.

```
public final class CrashHandler implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler
{
    @NonNull
    private final Context appContext;

    @NonNull
    private final Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler defaultHandler;

    public CrashHandler(@NonNull final Context appContext)
    {
        this.appContext = appContext;

        this.defaultHandler = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();

        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(@NonNull final Thread thread, @NonNull final Throwable sourceException)
    {
        try
        {
            final int flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_TASK_ON_HOME |
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY;

            final Intent activityIntent = new Intent(this.appContext, YourCrashNotificationActivity.class);
            activityIntent.setFlags(flags);

            this.appContext.startActivity(activityIntent);
        }
        catch (Throwable th)
        {
            th.printStackTrace();

            this.defaultHandler.uncaughtException(thread, sourceException);
        }
    }
}
```

And next how to instantiate it. It should be in the Application.onCreate callback,
(**don't forget to update your AndroidManifest.xml with your application class**):

```
public final class YourApplication extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    { 
        super.onCreate();

        new CrashHandler(this.getApplicationContext());
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your code. It suffers from the same problem. It looks all fine but doesn't launch the needed activity.

Comment: We use this code in our production apps and so far it works perfectly. Can you share the details of the Activity you wish to launch? does it use some specific code in its onCreate? how is it declared in the manifest?

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK You can't start an Activity from the Application Context. It'll throw an Exception, You'll probalby see it if you debug your app.

here's a nice overview of the different contexts and what they can be used for:
https://medium.com/@sevbanbuyer/context-in-android-97eda93dc777